# How to add the length to the end of a char array buffer in C language

Tags: c, iso8583

I have to send a ISO8583 message to an acquirer server and the switch want me to send the message with the APDU length before my whole message but i do not know how to send. The length is 4 bytes.

Example: i want to send the message (PAN-Expiry Date) 4427680000628820 1014

Header:30353530
Message:44276800006288201014

I want to send this through the socket: 30353530(00000014=20 in decimal) 4427680000628820 (PAN) 1014 (Exp)

Which should give me: 303535300000001444276800006288201014

Actually i do like this

```
buf[0]=0x30
buf[1]=0x35
buf[2]=0x35
buf[3]=0x30
```

How to add the length 00000014 after buf[3]?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: In the same manner as you added the other bytes, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply continue as you did with your first 4 bytes: Assuming your total message length, in your example 0x00000014, is stored in the 32 bit variable "len", add the length header with

```
buf[4] = (uint8_t)((len >> 24ul) & 0xFF);
buf[5] = (uint8_t)((len >> 16ul) & 0xFF);
buf[6] = (uint8_t)((len >> 8ul) & 0xFF);
buf[7] = (uint8_t)(len & 0xFF);
```

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can't "add length" to a char array in C.  Whether static or dynamically allocated, the size is fixed - there is no way to simply make it bigger.  You have to make a new larger array and copy the old bytes in.

```
char oldarray[4];
// fill it with stuff

// oops, too small
char newarray[8];
memcpy(newarray, oldarray, 4);

// move on with things
```